# Manifest for DPI Awareness

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, dpi-aware

I wanted to experiment with DPI-awareness.  I created the following manifest, but I get the error:

> Unable to create process: The application has failed to start because
>   its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.

Here's the manifest.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestversion="1.0">
 <assemblyIdentity
    type="win32"
    name="DpiAwarenessTest.exe"
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="*"/>
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity
type="win32"
name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
version="6.0.0.0"
publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
language="*"
processorArchitecture="*"/>
</dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

 <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
          <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel
              level="asInvoker"
              uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
      </trustInfo>

<asmv3:application xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
    <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
  </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

Comment: The dpi setting is not the problem. Strip that out and it still fails. Start from a manifest that works and make small changes.

Comment: Thanks @500.  I used the manifest from your link and it worked.